# How to extract thor task into gem and run it from bin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have thor tasks in one Thor class. I want to extract it to my_gem and use it like bin. It is possible? Now i move this task to lib/my_gem/thor/tasks and i add Thorfile to gem, then i create my_gem.rb in my_gem/bin, but it is didn't work. If anybody know another way, please help. Thanks!

Comment: If you add some details about your `my_gem.gemspec`, I may be able to improve my answer, by matching how `gem.executables` is set to how you have written the gemspec - showing how you manage the gem's `files` attribute should be enough, plus a clearer description of where exactly you have put the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, you need to add this, or similar to your `my_gem.gemspec` (this works for a gem created by `bundle gem`, and where files list has already been assigned):

```
Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  # All the other usual stuff, e.g.  gem.files  = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
end
```

The executables should then get correctly handled on `gem install` (or `bundle install` etc), and put on your path.

Also important: The executable script should start

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

The `.rb` extension is optional, and usually omitted for command-line scripts because otherwise you need to type it when invoking your script.